# AngularJS ng-repeat x times dynamic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Preface:

[image]

```
                 <input type="tel" ng-model="people" placeholder="6" maxlength="2">
                    </label>
                    <ion-item>
                    {{people}}
                        <i class="ion-man icon-large padding-right" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(people) track by $index"></i>
                    </ion-item>

$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);
}
```

I have an input wherein the user can type in a number. I follow it up with an ng-repeat. Currently the ng-repeat doesn't seem to be bound to the `people` model. How can I bind people to refresh the ng-repeat or perhaps  trigger it again on ng-change?

To clarify, the ng-repeat code does work  --- here is what happens when I replace `people` with `3`:

```
                        <span class="input-label">¿Cuanta gente hay en la mesa?</span>
                        <input type="tel" ng-model="people" placeholder="6" maxlength="2">
                    </label>
                    <ion-item>
                    {{people}}
                        <i class="ion-man icon-large padding-right" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(3) track by $index"></i>
                    </ion-item>
```

[image]

Comment: What does the getNumber() function look like?

Comment: The number of people is a telephone number?

Comment: As sort of said above, why `<input type="tel">` instead of `<input type="number">`? Also, you should consider showing the code for `getNumber()`. Maybe `people` is a String that your `getNumber()` function needs to use `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()` on.

Comment: `    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);
    }` is the code for `getNumber()` ; and i use input "tel" to get a particular keyboard popup on mobile devices -- http://ionicframework.com/html5-input-types/#tel tel is big keys; whereas number is small keys. In reality it will just be an integer...

Comment: maybe I should just make it a directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Array(num)` when `num` is a string will give you an array with 1 element and is functionally the same as `[num]`

You need to `parseInt` the string first so that you have a number.

```
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(parseInt(num, 10));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Worked perfectly. I'm new to angular, so I thought it was something else.. But I guess it was binding, just incompatible data types.